# Performing database read operations in repository for Android MVVM architecture

Tags: android, mvvm, repository, viewmodel

What is the best practice for accessing data from multiple database tables in MVVM architecture?

I am taking a hands-on approach to learn MVVM architecture by creating an Android app. I understand how the different components fit and work together. 
I am thinking of adding complexities to this application by adding multiple tables to the appDatabase and accessing them to form a request which can be used to invoke a web-service from the Repository layer.

My question: What is your opinion on the best practice? (a) Should I observe all the concerned database tables as LiveData in the activity and build my request there, and send it down to Repository via the ViewModel?, or
(b) Should I hide all of that from the activity and let repository handle all the data manipulation from the various tables?

I have 2 tables: item_table and address_table

```
@Entity(tableName = "item_table")
public class Item {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private int id;

    private String itemName;
    private String itemType;
    private String itemGroup;
    ...
}

@Entity(tableName = "address_table")
public class Address {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private int id;

    private String itemGroup;
    private String destinationAddress;
    ...
}
```

I have corresponding DAOs

```
@Dao
public interface ItemDao{
   @Query("SELECT * FROM item_table")
   LiveData<List<Item>> getAllItems();
}

@Dao
public interface AddressDao{
   @Query("SELECT * FROM address_table")
   LiveData<List<Address>> getAllAddresses();
}
```

And corresponding repositories:

```
public class ItemRepository{
   private ItemDao;
   private LiveData<List<Item>> allItems;
   public LiveData<List<Item>> getAllItems(){
      return allItems;
   }
   ...
}

public class AddressRepository{
   private AddressDao;
   private LiveData<List<Address>> allAddresses;
   public LiveData<List<Address>> getAllAddresses(){
      return allAddresses;
   }
   ...
}
```

With corresponding ViewModels:

```
public class ItemViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {
   private LiveData<List<Item>> allItems;
   ...
}

public class AddressViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {
   private LiveData<List<Address>> allAddresses;
   ...
}
```

My MainActivity.java observes the allItems LiveData:

```
private ItemViewModel itemViewModel;
itemViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(ItemViewModel.class);
itemViewModel.getAllQuickAccessDevices().observe(this, new 
Observer<List<Item>>() {
   @Override
   public void onChanged(@Nullable List<Device> devices) {
      //do stuff
      ...
   }
}
```

Based on the itemGroup of the corresponding item, I want to fetch the corresponding destinationAddress from address_table to initiate a web-service request using that destinationAddress.

What would be a good architectural design? 
(a) Should I observe the List in MainActivity and pass all the info down to repository, or,
(b) let repository manipulate the data from address_table?